# Triple integration for finding volume of cuboid

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, volume

How can I solve this:

$$\iiint\limits_B xyz^2\,dV$$

where $B$ is the cuboid bounded by the regions $0\leq x\leq 1$, $-1\leq y\leq 2$, and $0\leq z\leq 3$?

No idea friends!

Comment: Is it just $z$ which is squared, or is it $xyz$ which is squared?

Comment: it is only z squared.

Comment: I doubt that what I have written is what you have been asked to solve. Please check so I can edit appropriately. I think you should have $dzdydz$ (or similar) instead of $dV$.

Comment: I dont't know but this is the question given in my book.

Comment: It must be dxdydz.

Comment: If it is $dxdydz$, then the question is different from the original question you asked.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Many books and many of us use $dV$ to denote a multiple integral, as opposed to the iterated integral you then compute by applying Fubini's Theorem. What is the fuss about?

Comment: @TedShifrin: My comment referred to a different version of the question where there were limits on the integrals. In that case, writing $dV$ does not tell you which limits refer to which variables.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese:  Gotcha. We should just erase all these now irrelevant comments!

Answer (score 2):

If we let $\,dV=\,dx\,dy\,dz$, note that
$$\begin{aligned}\iiint\limits_B xyz^2\,dV &= \int_0^3\int_{-1}^2\int_0^1xyz^2\,dx\,dy\,dz\\ &= \left(\int_0^1x\,dx\right)\left(\int_{-1}^2y\,dy\right)\left(\int_0^3z^2\,dz\right) \\ &= \ldots\end{aligned} $$
I hope you can take things from here!

> The final answer is 6.75 ( http://wolfr.am/1kM2Rtn )

Comment: I tried this same method but answer is coming wrong.

Comment: What answer did you get when computing things this way? And if the answer is coming out wrong...what is the answer they're looking for?

Comment: @DevgeetPatel: The way, in this post, is the only answer. No other way can be derived. Don't worry, be brave and know that other answers are wrong. $\ddot\smile$